# Skip test case details are not flushed in ExtentReports. correct the below program

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Skip test case details are not flushed in ExtentReports.Here is my sample code. I am using ExtentReports dependency version <2.40.2>.
As per the below code once myTest() method fails the dependent test should be reported in the ExtentReport as skipped but I can see only passed testcase details. There is no details about skipped test case.
Suggest me the required changes or updates. **

```
package mypackage;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class ExtentTestLogs
{ 
  ExtentReports report;
  ExtentTest logger;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startTest() {
        report = new ExtentReports("E:\\Reports\\ExtentTestLogs.html", false);
        logger = report.startTest("log report is started");
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Before method");
    }
    @Test
    public void sampleTest(){
        logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "sample test is executed");
    }
    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"myTest"}) //skipped test
    public void skippedTest(){
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Skipped Test information");
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void endTest(ITestResult result) {
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
            logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"This test is failed");
            report.endTest(logger);
            report.flush();
        }
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS ){
            logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "This test is Passed");
            report.endTest(logger);
            report.flush();
        }
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
            logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "This test is skipped");//Expecting logger
            report.endTest(logger);
            report.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use ITestResult which checks the results at the end of the suite. But use a TestListener instead which will give you real time results.

Answer (score 0):

flush() "Appends the HTML file with all the ended tests."

close() needs to be called after ending the test and calling flush for the report to be flushed.

Try adding report.close() after flush() in your code.

Refer:
http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/